# Referencing `this` in React JSX

Tags: javascript, scope, reactjs, arrow-functions

I am writing a function in React JSX which contains callbacks that need to talk to `this`

```
    this.socket.on('addWashedMission', washedMission => {
        console.log('onAddWashedMission - %s - %s', washedMission.name, 
            new Date(washedMission.birthtime));

        this.state.washedMissions.filter(function(o) {
            return o.name === washedMission.name;
        }).forEach(function(element, i, arr) {
            // HERE IT IS //
            this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(
                this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element), 1);
        });

        this.state.washedMissions.push(washedMission);
        this.state.washedMissions.sort(function(a,b) {
            return b.birthtime - a.birthtime;
        });

        this.setState({
            washedMissions: this.state.washedMissions
        });
    });
```

Notice the `this.state.washedMissions`? When I am inside that callback, the Firefox script debugger shows me that the browser doesn't know what `this` is and thus I can't manipulate my arrays this way.

How can I ensure that `this` is within the scope of my callback -- and note, the callback is synchronous, so I am not worried about any timing stuff.

Comment: Since you're already using arrow function, why not use that for `forEach` too?

Comment: Li Yin Kong is correct. Use arrow functions in your forEach and problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more arrow functions for all of your functions

```
this.socket.on('addWashedMission', washedMission => {
    console.log('onAddWashedMission - %s - %s', washedMission.name, 
        new Date(washedMission.birthtime));

    this.state.washedMissions
        .filter(o => {
            return o.name === washedMission.name;
        })
        .forEach((element, i, arr) => {
            const elementIndex = this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element);
            this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(elementIndex, 1);
        });

    this.state.washedMissions.push(washedMission);
    this.state.washedMissions.sort((a,b) => {
        return b.birthtime - a.birthtime;
    });

    this.setState({
        washedMissions: this.state.washedMissions
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
...forEach(function(element, i, arr) {
  this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(
    this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element), 1);
});
```

You need to provide the `thisArg` as the second argument to [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
...forEach(function(element, i, arr) {
  this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(
    this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element), 1);
}, this); // <--- note the `this` after the function() {}
```

Or you need an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which lexically binds the `this` value

```
...forEach((element, i, arr) =>
  this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(
    this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element), 1)
);
```

Or you can use the stone-age-slow `Function.prototype.bind` provided in the other answer

Comment: Actually I wish I accepted this answer since you covered all 3 ways of getting this done!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in the scope of your anonymous function doesn't reference the containing scope where it was defined.  It will instead reference the scope of the object to which it is assigned and from which it is later called.

So you need to "trick" it to think `this` references the `this` you want it to.

There are a couple ways to achieve what you want.

1. Use a `var that = this;` definition outside your anonymous function, and and reference it within instead of `this` to create a closure. (Better backwards-compatibility for older browsers)

   ```
   var that = this;
   this.state.washedMissions.filter(function(o) {
       return o.name === washedMission.name;
   }).forEach(function(element, i, arr) {
       // HERE IT IS //
       that.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(
           that.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element), 1);
   });
   ```
2. Bind the scope of your anonymous function to the `this` of its defining scope before passing it in to the `forEach` method (preferred ECMA5 method for handling this)

   ```
   this.state.washedMissions.filter(function(o) {
       return o.name === washedMission.name;
   }).forEach(function(element, i, arr) {
       // HERE IT IS //
       this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.slice(
           this.state.washedMissions.state.washedMissions.indexOf(element), 1);
   }.bind(this));
   ```